# Axios React Native Token request from fatsecret.com

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, request, axios, access-token

I need to fetch an Oauth2.0 token from the fatsecret.com API, and would like to save it.

I have a little function to request a token but keep on getting an error 400...

If you could tell me how to fix this even maybe using fetch(), I would really appreciate it..

I have been stuck on this for so long...

Thanks in advance.

[image: Postman token call]

```
const clientId = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
const clientSecret = 'xxxxxxxx';

async authorize () {
   const data = {
      auth: {
         user : clientId,
         password : clientSecret
      }
    }
    const config = {
      headers: { 
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
      'scope' : 'premier',
      json: true
    }
    const res = await axios.post('https://oauth.fatsecret.com/connect/token', {data}, [{config}]);
    console.log(res.data);
  }
```

Comment: Have you checked the results of your api by using postman?

Comment: @user12129132 I added the postman screenshot above. It all works fine, just dont know how to translate that for react native... I hope you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use fetch like this:

```
    const clientId = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
    const clientSecret = 'xxxxxxxx';
    authorize () {
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('grant_type', 'client_credentials');
        formData.append('user', clientID);
        formData.append('password', clientSecret);
        formData.append('scope', 'basic');

        fetch('https://oauth.fatsecret.com/connect/token', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: formData
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
            console.log(responseData);
        });
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: YOU ARE A GENIUS. I have been stuck on this issue for the past 3 days. THANKS YOU SO MUCH FOR HELPING ME!!! I just have one more question, how do I store the token, since its read-only and how would I refresh it after 24h? Thank you so much once again!

Comment: Iam glad that I helped  you, you can store the token in async storage. Will your token expires for every 24 hrs

Comment: Yes, the token expires every 24 hours.

Comment: If you use async storage no need of expo eject.